# Global StreamController.broadcast() performance

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

Is it fine to use broadcast stream as Global Variable that can be accessed from any widget?

Is this good practice or might cause performance issues?

Or I have to close the stream soon its done?

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {

  static final socialStreamController = StreamController<T>.broadcast();

  const MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text('test');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as it is a singleton and you close it when you no longer use it, I don't see a major performance problem, only if these two conditions are met.

Comment: The thing is Global variable can't be closed. and if closed can't reopened again.

Comment: Specifficaly what its the purpose of this stream, what contains?

Comment: Stream is related to specific screen. Its children will add/listen to events and act accordingly.